# ibus package not found while trying to build gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: development, ibus, gnome-settings-daemon

I'm currently trying to build `gnome-settings-daemon` from the upstream source. I first cloned the package using

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-settings-daemon
```

then navigated into the directory and started the build process with

```
./autogen
```

However, I ended up with the following error:

```
checking for KEYBOARD... no
configure: error: Package requirements (xkbfile ibus-1.0 >= 1.4.99 gnome-desktop-3.0 >= 3.7.90) were not met:

No package 'ibus-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables KEYBOARD_CFLAGS
and KEYBOARD_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have the `ibus` and `ibus-gtk3` packages installed, so I'm not sure what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found two possible solutions to this. The first is to install the `ibus` development package (as opposed to the release package) using

```
sudo apt-get install libibus-dev
```

Alternatively, the build can be carried out without iBus at all by running

```
./autogen.sh --disable-ibus
```

Comment: Or try: `sudo apt-get install libibus-1.0-dev`